# Dividing a matrix in cells in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have

1) a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `mx1`, e.g. `m=10`

```
A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]
```

2) a vector `B` of dimension `nx1`, e.g. `n=2`

```
B=[2; 1]
```

3) a vector `C` of dimension `nx1`, e.g.

```
C=[3; 4]
```

It should be that the sum over `i` of `C(i)*B(i)` is equal to `m`. In the example `3*2+4*1=10`.

I want to generate a cell `C` of dimension `1xsum(B,1)` composed by `sum(B,1)` sub-cells. The sub-cells should be created looking at `B` and `C`: `B(i)` and `C(i)` tell that we have to take `B(i)` groups of `C(i)` elements of `A` each. In the example,

```
C={{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9 10}}
```

Comment: From your two parameters b an c, you need to get the sizes of each cell, for you example D=[3,3,4] . That's run length decoding and answered in multiple questions here. If you got D, use mat2cell to split A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an `arrayfun` and `repmat` combo. There is probably a more efficient way to do it though.

```
A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10] ;
B=[2; 1] ;
C=[3; 4];
q = arrayfun(@(x, y) repmat(x(:), 1, y), C, B, 'uni', 0);
Ap = mat2cell(A(:), [q{:}]);
Ap{:}
```

Output

```
ans =

     1
     2
     3


ans =

     4
     5
     6


ans =

     7
     8
     9
    10
```